# FeatureExtraction for TimeSeries giving errors

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to replicate [this example](https://wolfram.com/xid/01ywczzauqq-4xpij) using FeatureExtraction for TimeSeries. However, it's giving errors.

Here's the code I've run:

```
examples = {TimeSeries[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}], TimeSeries[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}]}
fe = FeatureExtraction[examples]
```

This gives a long list of errors I've pasted here: https://pastebin.com/7DMbdNKf

How do I fix this? Is it a bug?

Note I'm using Mathematica 13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)

Comment: Until other users have confirmed your observations, do not add the [tag:bugs] tag to your question.

Comment: If I set `SeedRandom[1]` and run your code, then NO error on V12.3, Linux.

Comment: @user293787 setting `SeedRandom[1]` gives the same errors. anyway, I've changed the example so it's easier to reproduce